# Is there a way to make Selenium Grid 2 DesiredCapabilities browser-agnostic?

Tags: selenium-grid

I'm wondering if there's a (preferably built-in) way for Selenium hubs to ask for nodes that have any browser available. Basically, I want my hub to specify something like "BrowserName = 'any'", match on a node that is running less instances than its maxInstances, then let the node decide which browser to run on.

The motivation behind this is that I want to maximize the number of tests running in parallel on any given node without having multiple instances of any one browser. I don't care which browser is running for any given test.

As a reference, I'm currently using selenium server 2.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ack, this is annoying.

I'm fairly sure there's a command line parameter that let's you override the specified browserName, but now I can't find it.

If my memory is not way off, the parameter let you do more or less what you are asking for - regardless of what browsers the node *says* it has, and regardless of what the hub *asks for*, one particular browser is always started.

Note to self: start a proper list of all command line options for selenium, and possibly submit it to the team for inclusion in the wiki.

One way to achieve this in any case would be to write a your own "CapabilityMatcher" class - but that may not be an option unless you want to create a custom JAR, and you want teh *hub* to do the change of browser, rather than the individual nodes.

Comment: OK - found it, and it's called "forcedBrowserMode".  It seems that it only applies to "Selenium-RC", and not Webdriver though.

http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/e297bee96740c0a?fwc=1
http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/docs/twist/2.0/help/how_do_i_configure_selenium.html
https://gist.github.com/1647013

Comment: Awesome, I think this should accomplish what I need (one way or another).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.14.0.jar -role node  -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -maxSession 3 -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=1 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=1` ...

Comment: I'm not sure this accomplishes what I described. If I'm not mistaken, this will register the node with all capabilities open, but the hub will still have to specify a browser in the DesiredCapabilities. My nodes currently register with three browser capabilities (Chrome, Firefox, and IE), but the hub has to loop through asking for these three (catching exceptions along the way) to ensure that all three browsers are running simultaneously. I want a way for the hub to say "run this test on a node with any browsers free" and let the node pick any of its open ones.